# How to show multiple Alerts one after another in iphone app

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uialertview

Hi 
let me explain briefly.

i am developing an iphone application where i have to show multiple UIAlerts one after the another, 
but if i simply use multiple `[alert show];` they all show up stacking up to each other.
one solution is to show one alert `[alert1 show];` then in

```
- (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex
```

detect the end of first alert1 then show the second alert by calling `[alert2 show];` and so on continue to show other alerts using **alertView**.

i want to know is there any other way to show multiple alerts in a sequence without the pain of using  **alertView** to detect end of first alert and then show the second one ?

Answer (score 1):

In short, there is no other way. A slight better way might be that you can save the pending alerts in a mutable array and then pop next one (if any) in the delegate so that you don't have to go in a long if-else sequence. You can write your own alert queue in this way.

Comment: yah that could be one another solution :-)